# Is there a way to return a result from a walker without reporting it using jaseci

Tags: python

Is there a way to return a result from a walker without reporting it using jaseci.

because when you report stuff in general it queues up in the final report which we don't need.

```
report: [
{"response": "xyz"}
];

instead of

report: [
"jdsjdbjs",
"dndkfndkfn",
{"response": "xyz"}
];
```

it messes up with picking out records

Comment: additionally for example if I am spawing a walker within a walker it would have the report for both of them when actually I only need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case there are two solutions:

1. If you need to return something from a walker to its caller, you can use `has anchor` in the walker being called. This will be "return" value of the walker spawn statement. For example,

```
walker B {
  has anchor X;
  X = 5;
}
walker A {
  Y = spawn here walker::B;
}
```

In this example, `Y` will be assigned the value of `5` when walker B finishes walking.

2. If you are using the same walker in different scenarios where sometimes you need it to report and sometimes you don't. What I usually do is to just create a parameter for the walker, something like `if_report` and just report when it is set to True.

Comment: amazing this works like a charm, I never knew this.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it would be nice if Jac had some more language features around this but you can check out "report custom" support. Its described here https://docs.jaseci.org/docs/docs/Developing_with_JAC/Language_Features/report_custom.html (docs arn't very good atm). Also keep in mind that once you set `report:custom` = that exact jsonized object will be reported after the run. (You wont get the full walker dictionary that includes "report", "success", etc etc.

Also note the last executed `report:custom` will be the only report returned.

Here are some examples:

```
walker cust_report{
    report:custom = {'a': 'b'}; 
}

walker cust_report_neutralize{ # this walker will report nothing
    report:custom = {'a': 'b'};
    report:custom = null; 
}

walker disengage_report{ # this walker will report {'a': 'b'}
    disengage report:custom = {'a': 'b'};
    report:custom = null; 
}
```